# Having a list of values, get them two by two and create an array with keys and values pairs

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using PHP and I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5 star
    [1] => 65%
    [2] => 4 star
    [3] => 19%
    [4] => 3 star
    [5] => 9%
    [6] => 2 star
    [7] => 3%
    [8] => 1 star
    [9] => 4%
    [10] => See all 931 reviews
)
```

I would like to build an array as the following:

```
Array
(
    [5star] => 65%
    [4star] => 19%
    [3star] => 9%
    [2star] => 3%
    [1star] => 4%
    [reviews] => 931
)
```

A part from the last key-value pair that needs some string manipulation, is there a more efficient/elegant way to achieve the above result rather creating two separate arrays and then pushing their values into a third one?

Comment: You can loop over the array with a step of 2 and check if element `$i+1` exists. Depending on where the data comes from, you can also fix that.

Comment: why don't you combine the 5 star and the percentage in one value and add the separator, for exmaple array[0] = "5 star#65%". and then you can split them later.

Comment: Both are good ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can only suggest ol' plain `while`:

```
$r = [];
$c = count($source);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $c - 1) {
    $r[$source[$i]] = $source[$i + 1];
    $i += 2;
}

$r[] = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $source[$i]); // add the last 'nnn reviews' bit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $newArray = array();
    for($i=0;$i <= count($yourArrayname);$i++))
    {
    $key = $yourArrayname[$i];
    $i++;
    $value = $yourArrayname[$i];
    $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
```